# Obtain particular ID to use for page auto redirect

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

User clicks Add unique 1 in add2.php. Add unique 1 holds a unique value each time the page loads.
Upon click the value of Add unique 1 (unique_value_1 in this example) is inserted into a DB table.
I would like to get the corresponding ID (Auto increment) from the table corresponding to the newly inserted value. 
This page is accessible by multiple users so there is no guarantee that the corresponding ID is the last inserted ID so I based a query on the unique value name. I can't seem to return the ID as a JQuery variable. 
I want to return the ID to use in an auto page redirect from add2.php after click e.g. window.location.href = "NewPage.php?value=CorrespondingID".
Please recommend an approach.

add2.php:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" 
 src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js">    
 </script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {

 $(document).on('click', '#1', function(){
 var variable = $('#1').attr('value');
 var DATA = 'unique_variable='+variable;

 $.ajax                  
 ({
 type: "POST",
 url: "index2.php",
 data: DATA,
 cache: false,
 success: function(data){
                        alert("Added!");
                        $.post('last.php',   
                        {'unique_variable':variable},function(data)
                    {  
                    $(".last").load("last.php?  unique_variable="+variable);
                    });
                    var last = $(".last").val();
                    alert(last);
                    }
                    });
}); 
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="1" value="unique_value_1">Add unique 1</button><br/>
<div class="last"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

index2.php:

```
include 'connect.php';
$unique_variable = $_POST['unique_variable'];
$insert_status=mysql_query('INSERT INTO `test2` (`id`,`variable`) VALUES   
("","'.$unique_variable.'")') or die (mysql_error());
```

last.php:

```
include 'connect.php';
error_reporting(0);
$unique_variable = $_GET['unique_variable'];
$added = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test2 where    
variable='$unique_variable'");

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($added))
            {
            $added_variable=$row['id'];
            }
echo $added_variable;
```